# Ubuntu stuck in boot up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bootable

Previously I kept getting stuck in the GNU Grub terminal so I followed the instructions 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen) to fix it. I set root, and used set linux and initrd then typed boot. which led me to this screen.
[image: stuck while booting]

It seems like it did a bunch of booting stuff and got stuck. I'm not sure, I'm very new to linux. This is booting from a USB, which works on a desktop, but not this Asus Zenbook laptop. Secure Boot and Fast Boot have both been disabled. I'm not sure what's wrong, please help..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to re-install Ubuntu on this machine. The message shown in the screenshot is a Kernel Panic and means that Ubuntu had some trouble with the hardware. Most likely a misconfiguration somewhere, which a new install should fix.